# UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity sometimes failing with DirectoryServicesCOMException: An operations error occurred

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, active-directory, claims-based-identity

We are a team where everyone of us experience this somewhat random error. The error is listed below and appears on the line: UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, windowsPrincipal.Identity.Name);

**It works just fine several days/weeks/months, and then one of us get this error.**

On our test server, where we do not deploy changes to as frequently as our local machines, it works for many months before we get this error.

If we change the application pool from ApplicationPoolIdentity to NetworkService, that works. However, after switching back to ApplicationPoolIdentity the same error appears.

IISreset does not help.

Rebooting the computer always solves the problem, so the ApplicationPoolIdentity has no problems to authenticate us on a daily basis.

This is the code (somewhat modified) that we use:

```
var windowsPrincipal = principal as WindowsPrincipal;
if (windowsPrincipal == null)
    return null;
try
{
    var principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
    var userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, windowsPrincipal.Identity.Name);
    if (userPrincipal == null) return null;
    return userPrincipal.Surname;
}
```

Here is the error message:

```
An operations error occurred.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException: An operations error occurred.

Source Error:
var principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
var userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, windowsPrincipal.Identity.Name);

Stack Trace:


[DirectoryServicesCOMException (0x80072020): An operations error occurred.
]
   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail) +628309
   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind() +44
   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject() +42
   System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection.PopulateList() +29
   System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection..ctor(DirectoryEntry entry, String propertyName) +63
   System.DirectoryServices.PropertyCollection.get_Item(String propertyName) +163
   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoLDAPDirectoryInitNoContainer() +521413
   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoDomainInit() +51
   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.Initialize() +161
   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.get_QueryCtx() +42
   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.FindByIdentityWithTypeHelper(PrincipalContext context, Type principalType, Nullable`1 identityType, String identityValue, DateTime refDate) +29
   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext context, String identityValue) +81
```

Comment: Just an idea - are you properly disposing your PrincipalContexts?

Comment: Post the block of code causing the exception.

Comment: @Daro: I have just updated with the code causing the exception.

Comment: @WiktorZychla: Thanks for the advice. I have changed our code, and we will try it out for a while now. I put the principalContext in a 'using' block

Comment: Thanks @Daro, I will try this for a month now and see if this solves our problem. If it does, I'm not sure how to mark your answer as the correct one, as you deserve all the credit.

Comment: Okay.  I changed my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not disposing it in a finaly block, you'll eventually run out of resources...

```
Using (var principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain)) 
{
var userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, 
  windowsPrincipal.Identity.Name);
if (userPrincipal == null) return null;
  return userPrincipal.Surname;
}
```

should help

Comment: We are still facing this problem, even after the Using statement. I really thought that it would solve our problem, but unfortunately the error remains.

Comment: You could observe the task manager to see if the handle count from the IIS process continusly climbs. (Processes / View / Select Columns... / Handles)

Comment: I tried this, and the number of handles for the iis process that has the error is around 500. Some of the other iis processes have more than the double amount of handles, and they run fine (but they do not run any code against the UserPrincipal).

And I just can't explain why it does not work when I run as the ApplicationPoolIdentity, but when I switch to the NetworkService, it works just fine.

Comment: Look here: http://microsoft.public.adsi.general.narkive.com/v2QJLsEh/credentials-for-principalcontext it is explained some why NetworkService should be used.